# HtmlUnit returning empty loginForm set

Tags: java, htmlunit

I am trying to find the loginform data from the Nike website. I've added a timer to wait for the loginform to be populated but it still outputs as an empty set. I've have also tried searching for the form by name.
I would appreciate any help in solving this issue.
*Also the code below will output warnings but it is a htmlUnit library issue, code will compile, and run*

[Nike loginForm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVgyc.png)

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public static void main( String[] args ) throws IOException, Exception
    {
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);

        HtmlPage loginPage = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://www.nike.com/login?continueUrl=https://www.nike.com/");

        webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(6000);
        System.out.println( loginPage.getForms() );
    }
```

I've also tried to retrieve the loginForm by using this code block but been unsuccessful.

```
System.out.println( loginPage.getByXPath("//form[@id='nike-unite-loginform']") );
HtmlForm form = loginPage.getFormByName("nike-unite-loginForm");
List<HtmlForm> formList = (List<HtmlForm>) loginPage.getForms();
HtmlInput htmlEmail = loginPage.getElementByName("emailAddress");
```

Comment: I'm afraid htmlunit can't process all the Javascript on that page. The login form is not part of the sources of the page, so it's probably generated by Javascript. If you look at the debug/logging output of htmlunit you can see a lot of Javascript errors. Perhaps you could try to report it as a bug, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56207479/18699445

Comment: try to use playwright https://playwright.dev/java/